# "ImportError: No module named xlsxwriter" while converting python script to .exe

Tags: python, xlsx, xlsxwriter

My script is working fine if I run it as Python from the command line. 
I have converted the script to an `.exe` and am facing an issue with `xlswrite`. Below is the error output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 27, in <module>
    exec code in m.__dict__
  File "loader.py", line 5, in <module>
ImportError: No module named xlsxwriter
```

I have used [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XHcDHSWRCRQ) to create the `.exe` for my Python script.

How should I fix the import error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have only used `cx_freeze` a few times and was successful using these steps. You were possibly missing something in this. First, create a `setup.py` like so:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys

exe = Executable(
    script="yourmodule.py",
    base="Win32GUI",
    )

setup(
    name = "desiredname",
    version = "1",
    description = "example program",
    executables = [exe]
    )
```

Before running this, make sure that you have **all non-default (built-in) modules** and the `setup.py` file in the same folder as the `yourmodule.py` file. Then from the command line, run `python setup.py build`.

Comment: i put my all working files with in c:\python27 folder. earlier i have installed the xlswrite package in c:\python27\script folder. so where thing is under one folder. while running "python setup.py build" i am getting error **"Missing modules: ?xlsxwriter.workbook imported from abc__main__"**

Comment: i would suggest taking all of the xlsxwriter files and putting them in the same folder as the setup.py

Comment: it sounds like cx_freeze was not able to find the xlsxwriter, as it does not sound like a built in package.